# Merge 2 sorted Stacks recursively

Tags: java, recursion, merge, stack

I want to write a method in java which merges two sorted Stacks like stack1 = [5, 4, 2] and stack2 = [6, 3, 1]. The return value should be the still sorted Stack [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]. The method should be recursive and without use of a helper method. So the method stub is:

```
public static Stack<Integer> merge(Stack<Integer> stack1, Stack<Integer> stack2){...}
```

Unfortunately I haven't a clue so I'd be happy about some help:)

Comment: Are the stacks the same size?

Comment: No  they don't have to

Comment: This doesn't meet your requirements, but this is the modern way to accomplish your goal in two statements: `stack1.addAll(stack2); Stack<Integer> out = stack1.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));`

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is tagged with Java but the question is not too clear in terms of the nature of the recursive solution. If this is what you were looking for, I can write up a Java version too:

```py
def merge(x, y):
    if x:
        if not y:
            return []
        v = x.pop()
        s = []
        while y[-1] < v:
            s.append(y.pop())
        y.append(v)
        while s:
            y.append(s.pop())
        return merge(x, y)
    else:
        return y
```

Comment: No wait its brilliant sorry XD. I'll try my best to convert it to java code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's separate to cases:

- Both stacks are empty - return new stack.
- Only one stack is empty - pop integer, call recursively to myself then push the popped integer to the returned stack.
- Both stacks have integers - pop the **bigger** integer, call recursively to myself, then push the popped integer to the returned stack.

When *I called recursively to myself*, I got a sub-merged stack and this is why it works.

Now it's simple to code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static Stack<Integer> merge(Stack<Integer> s1, Stack<Integer> s2) {
        if (!s1.empty() && s2.empty()) {
            Integer pop = s1.pop();
            Stack<Integer> merge = merge(s1, s2);
            merge.push(pop);

            return merge;
        } else if (s1.empty() && !s2.empty()) {
            Integer pop = s2.pop();
            Stack<Integer> merge = merge(s1, s2);
            merge.push(pop);

            return merge;
        } else if (s1.empty() && s2.empty()) {
            return new Stack<>();
        } else {
            Integer pop;

            if (s1.peek() > s2.peek()) {
                pop = s1.pop();
            } else {
                pop = s2.pop();
            }

            Stack<Integer> merge = merge(s1, s2);
            merge.push(pop);
            return merge;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<>(), s2 = new Stack<>();
        s1.addAll(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 5));
        System.out.println("First stack is: " + s1);
        s2.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6));
        System.out.println("Second stack is: " + s2);

        Stack<Integer> merge = merge(s1, s2);
        System.out.println("Merged stack is: " + merge);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First stack is: [2, 4, 5]
Second stack is: [1, 3, 6]
Merged stack is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks That's perfect. I had something similar before and it didn't work. Don't know why but it is what is. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Thyrexx Please consider accepting an answer. :)